# Simplified Kata of BankOCR using Shapeless

Tags: scala

I attempted to solve a simplification of [User Story 2](http://codingdojo.org/kata/BankOCR/) using shapeless:

Namely, define the implementation of:

```
trait IsValid[A]
object IsValid {

  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: IsValid[L]) = ev
}
```

where `valid` means (per my simplification):

> given 2 digits, it's valid if (A * 1 + b * 0) mod 5 == 0

So, `(5, 0)` is valid since `(5*1) + (0*0) mod 5 == 0` is true.

But, `(4, 1)` is not since it does not satisfy the above equation.

Here's my full implementation:

```
package net

import shapeless._, ops.hlist.IsHCons
import nat._
import ops.nat.{ Mod, Prod, Sum }

trait IsValid[A]
object IsValid {

  // simplified: given 2 digits, it's valid if (A * 1 + b * 0) mod 5 == 0
  def apply[L <: HList](implicit ev: IsValid[L]) = ev

  implicit def validNumber[L <: HList, H <: HList, A <: Nat, B <: Nat, 
                P1 <: Nat, P2 <: Nat, S <: Nat](
     implicit evA: IsHCons.Aux[L, A, H],
     evB: IsHCons.Aux[H, B, HNil],
     prod1: Prod.Aux[_1, A, P1],
     prod2: Prod.Aux[_0, B, P2],
     sum: Sum.Aux[P1, P2, S],
     mod: Mod.Aux[S, _5, _0]
   ): IsValid[L] = new IsValid[L] {}

}
```

Testing:

```
// (5*1) + (10*0) mod 5 === 0 (true)
scala> IsValid[_5 :: _10 :: HNil]
res4: net.IsValid[shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._5,shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._10,shapeless.HNil]]] = net.IsValid$$anon$1@160627b3

// (10*1) + (10*0) mod 5 === 0 (true)
scala> IsValid[_10 :: _10 :: HNil]
res5: net.IsValid[shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._10,shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._10,shapeless.HNil]]] = net.IsValid$$anon$1@3f3f03a3

// (3*1) + (10*0) mod 5 === 0 (false)
scala> IsValid[_3 :: _0 :: HNil]
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: net.IsValid[shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._3,shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._0,shapeless.HNil]]]
       IsValid[_3 :: _0 :: HNil]
              ^

// 3 digits are not allowed, only 2
scala> IsValid[_5 :: _0 :: _1 :: HNil]
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: net.IsValid[shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._5,shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._0,shapeless.::[shapeless.nat._1,shapeless.HNil]]]]
       IsValid[_5 :: _0 :: _1 :: HNil]
              ^
```

Please critique my approach.